# WildFly jdbc connection with Sybase

Tags: java, jdbc, sap-ase, wildfly-10

I'm trying to migrate from Glassfish to WildFly 10, my app connects whit Sybase ASE database. I put jconn3.jar in WILDFLY_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\com\sybase\sybase\main, created the module.xml there with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.sybase.sybase">  
  <resources>  
    <resource-root path="jconn3.jar"/>  
  </resources>  
  <dependencies>  
    <module name="javax.api"/>  
  </dependencies>  
</module>
```

and inserted to the standalone.xml:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/FRAME_IBS" pool-name="FRAME_IBS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:5000/Banksys;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>sybase</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <driver-class>
            com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
        </driver-class>
        <security>
            <user-name>admin</user-name>
            <password>admin</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="sybase" module="com.sybase.sybase">
            <datasource-class>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDataSource</datasource-class>
            <xa-datasource-class>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

I got this error in server.log file when I started WF:

```
2017-02-17 12:48:56,297 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "FRAME_IBS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/FRAME_IBS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.FRAME_IBS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase]"
    ]
}
2017-02-17 12:48:56,297 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "FRAME_IBS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/FRAME_IBS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.FRAME_IBS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.FRAME_IBS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase]"
    ]
}
2017-02-17 12:48:56,453 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.sybase (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.data-source.FRAME_IBS, service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/FRAME_IBS]
```

I googled it and tried all that I found but still have this error. Please, help me.
Excuse if my english it´s not correct, it's not my native language.

I rename module and move it to WILDFLY_HOME\modules following Leozeo and Mark recommendations, and still have the same message. I remove my datasource from standalone.xml, run WF again, and I se this message:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "sybase")
```

File module.xml and .jar are both present now in WILDFLY_HOME\modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have driver installed properly. Check that driver jar and module.xml file are present in WILDFLY_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\com\sybase\main directory.

**update value of name attribute**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.sybase">  
   <resources>  
     <resource-root path="jconn3.jar"/>  
   </resources>  
   <dependencies>  
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
  </dependencies>  
</module>
```

Comment: The Wildfly documentation suggest to put your own modules under `WILDFLY_HOME\modules`, the location `WILDFLY_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\` is for Wildfly's own modules.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My suggestion will  Install a JDBC Driver as a Core Module of WildFly and it will be available globally.

Comment: I don't use wildly daily, but rooting it in modules has the same effect afaik.

Comment: Thank to both, but the inconvenient persist

Comment: @FlorenciaRivadeneira I use wildfly 9 with Oracle and Postgresql. Instructions are same but the directory path changes as per driver name. For Oracle, driver name is "com.oracle.Driver" so the ojdbc.jar goes under WILDFLY_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\com\oracle\main directory.
For postgresql(enterprise) driver name is "org.edb.Driver" so edb-jdbc17.jar will go under WILDFLY_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\edb\main directory.

Comment: @Maverick thank you! It worked with the changes in the directory like you show in above answer!